# How do I call function outside async function in puppeteer with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

how do I call a function passing the page object outside async method in puppeteer.

I want to implement a functionality where if a certain value is found on page it should play a music. I have defined playmusic() functionality outside async method .

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const playmusic = ()=>{
   page.goto('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2544');
   page.click('span.map_play');
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false});
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();

 
  await page.goto('DesiredURL');
  const pricing = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    let pricesOnPage=document.querySelectorAll(".span_price_wrap");
    const priceList=[...pricesOnPage];
    return priceList.map(h=>h.innerText);
    
  });
  console.log(pricing[1]);

  if(pricing[1]>=2316)
  {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      playmusic ();
    });
  }

 await browser.close();
})();
```

I m getting below error

```
\index.js
2346.75
(node:17316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: playmusic is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:6
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (\jswebscrapping\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (\jswebscrapping\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
    at async index.js:24:4
(node:17316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17316) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

### ------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------

Sharing the workable code: Thanks everyone for helping
I have improved my code in couple of places such as

1. added wait time before and after playing the music .
2. Converted return value in float ( earlier it was treated as string )

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

 const playmusic = async (page)=>{
  await page.goto('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2544');
  await page.waitFor(4000) ;
  await page.click('span.map_play');
  await page.waitFor(12000);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false});
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();

 
  await page.goto('MYURL');
  const pricing = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    let pricesOnPage=document.querySelectorAll(".span_price_wrap");
    const priceList=[...pricesOnPage];
    return priceList.map(h=>h.innerText);
    

  });
  console.log(pricing[1]);
  let PricingFloat= parseFloat(pricing[1]);

  if(PricingFloat<=21)
  {
    await playmusic (page);   
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("No Music for you");
  }

 await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: yes, that's how you call a function - are you having an issue with the code? Oh, I see now ...if you want to pass the page, you would `playmusic(page)` and define playmusic like `const playmusic = page =>`

Comment: yes I m getting an error while executing . Let me share the error . 
node .let me edit my question with error

Comment: nevermind, I see what you did wrong and suggested a fix

Comment: "Sharing the workable code..." should be posted [as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question), not an edit to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
const playmusic = ()=>{
   page.goto('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2544');
   page.click('span.map_play');
}
```

by

```
const playmusic = (page) => {
   page.goto('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2544');
   page.click('span.map_play');
}
```

and

```
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      playmusic ();
    });
```

by

```
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      playmusic (page);
    });
```

Because of range when `page` exists is constrained and when you define function `playmusic` then this function do not have access to variable `page`. You can read more about `variables scopes` in JS.

Link to a great article:

> https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

---

UPDATE

After analyzing your code of error I think you need to add a try-catch block. For example.

```
try {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      playmusic (page);
    });
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   process.exit(1)
}
```

You should also check if the puppeteer does not have unrejected promised:

> https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-class-page

For example, you can write:

```
const playmusic = async (page) => {
   await page.goto('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2544');
   return page.click('span.map_play');
}
```

and in your main code:

```
try {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      try {
         await playmusic();
      } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
          process.exit(1);
      }
    });
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   process.exit(1)
}
```

Comment: I have made changes to code as per your suggestion However its not playing music even if the condition is met. https://pastebin.com/CZVb0jZr Do have a look . thanks for your help .

Comment: The top `const playmusic = (page) => {` is wrong and misleading--those Puppeteer calls that return promises need to be awaited, otherwise it's a race condition. You fixed it below, but I'd remove the top version completely. There's [no need to use "edit:"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) when updating--just make the edit. Thanks.